# Constructors and Inheritence

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I was wondering how to use a superclass constructor in a subclass but need to instantiate fewer attributes in the subclass. Below are the two classes. I'm not even sure if I'm doing things right currently. In the second class, there's an error that says "Implicit super constructor PropertyDB() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor." Note that this code is obviously incomplete and there is code that's commented out.

```
public abstract class PropertyDB {

private int hectares;

    private String crop;

    private int lotWidth;

    private int lotDepth;

    private int buildingCoverage;

    private int lakeFrontage;

    private int numBedrooms;

    private int listPrice;


    //public abstract int getPricePerArea();
    //public abstract int getPricePerBuildingArea();

    public PropertyDB(int newHectares, String newCrop, int newLotWidth, int newLotDepth, 
            int newBuildingCoverage, int newLakeFrontage, int newNumBedrooms, int newListPrice){
        hectares = newHectares;
        crop = newCrop;
        lotWidth = newLotWidth;
        lotDepth = newLotDepth;
        buildingCoverage = newBuildingCoverage;
        lakeFrontage = newLakeFrontage;
        numBedrooms = newNumBedrooms;
        listPrice = newListPrice;
    }
}


public class FarmedLand extends PropertyDB{


    public FarmedLand(int newHectares, int newListPrice, String newCorn){
        //super(270, 100, "corn");

        hectares = newHectares;
        listPrice = newListPrice;
        corn = newCorn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implicit constructor `PropertyDB()` exists only if you do not define any other constructors, in which case you will have to explicitly define `PropertyDB()` constructor.

The reason you see this error "Implicit super constructor PropertyDB() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor." is that in your `public FarmedLand(int newHectares, int newListPrice, String newCorn)` constructor, `super()` is automatically called as the first statement, which does not exist in your superclass.

Here's a simplified example:

```
public class A { }
```

can be instantiated by using `A a = new A()` because `public A() { }` is an implicit constructor of class A.

```
public class A {
    public A(int z) { /* do nothing*/ }
}
```

can *not* be instantiated using `A a = new A()` because by defining an explicit constructor `public A(int z)` the implicit one is no longer available.

Moving onto constructors and inheritance, from [Java Language Specification section 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body is implicitly assumed by the compiler to begin with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

So in your case the first statement executed in `public FarmedLand(int newHectares, int newListPrice, String newCorn)` constructor is an implicit call to `super();`, which in your case is not defined implicitly (there's already a `public PropertyDB(int, String, ...)` constructor defined) or explicitly (it's not in the source code)

Comment: I'm still a beginner but this seems helpful. Could you explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a derived class which `extends` a base class, the base class always gets constructed before the derived class. If you don't explicitly specify which constructor to use for the base class (like in your example), Java assumes you meant the parameterless constructor (in your case the `PropertyDB()` constructor).

But wait - `PropertyDB` doesn't have a parameterless constructor! So your only option is to use `super` so the Java compiler knows which constructor to call for the base class. In your case, there's only one constructor to choose from, so you have to use it with all 8 arguments. If you want to use less arguments, you either have to specify "default" values (like pass a `0`), or else define more constructors for `PropertyDB` which take fewer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're witnessing is due to the fact that the `PropertyDB` class doesn't have a default (no-arguments) constructor. Either create it in `PropertyDB` or call the existing superclass constructor `PropertyDB(int newHectares, String newCrop, int newLotWidth, int newLotDepth, int newBuildingCoverage, int newLakeFrontage, int newNumBedrooms, int newListPrice)` from the `FarmedLand` constructor using `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `super(newHectares, newCorn, 0, 0, 0, 0, newListPrice);` instead. 0 is the default value of the `int` anyway.

Comment: I thought of this solution earlier but if I wanted to not set any attributes to 0 or null, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @ProgrammingKeener each field of the class should have a value.

Comment: If you don't set attributes explicitly, Java will set them for you - in `0` for numeric types, `false` for booleans and `null` for object types

Answer (score 0):

Your superclass only has one constructor, so your subclass constructor must call it. There's no way around this: the superclass has (for example) a `lotWidth` field, so the subclass necessarily has that field, and the superclass initializes that field in its constructor, so it will necessarily be initialized in the subclass.

So, unless you modify the superclass in some way, you're going to have to call `super(...)` as the very first thing in the subclass constructor, specifying values for all its parameters.